# how can I find full text "Arabic" string value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have one column of type *nvarchar* that contain *Arabic characters* and we want to search **complete string text** in this column.

I found some answers here like:

```
select Description from OldTable where Description like N'%[أ-ي]%'

select Description from OldTable where Description does not contain 'Arabic characters'

select Description from OldTable where Description contains 'Arabic characters'
```

which these kind of answers work great but just to find all strings which contain "an" specific Arabic *character* while we want to find complete exact Arabic String text in a column.

Comment: pls. tag DB Version which you are using.

Comment: You say you have some answers. Have you tried them?

Comment: yes I treid all of them

Comment: have you collate like that  ARABIC_CI_AI ??

Comment: I try this just now, change the colation to Arabic but does not help me.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Also I must say sql2000 does not have ARABIC_CI_AI and I used windows Arabic collation